# Bypass dice poker quest in Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is there a way to bypass the stupid 'play dice with dwarf to 'win' a required quest item' in Witcher 2?
I hate chance based mini games and it's ridiculous that the game designer would force you to play one to progress a main quest. 
I'm looking for something similar to the Elder Scrolls series where each quest has an ID and you can set the progress of the quest via console commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, just play. Dice poker is a game of chance, sure, but a round takes 30 seconds and you only need to win once. You'll have a much easier time just playing than trying to bypass it.

Witcher 2 has no console commands, you'd have to create a mod, which removes the need to play dice poker.

[This mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/695/?) allows you to win by simply throwing all the dice off the table. It's the best I can offer.

Comment: That mod was what helped me a lot while playing Witcher 2. But maybe because of it I never really got good at dice poker.

Comment: There really is no way to get good at dice poker. It's purely luck, even more so than it was in Witcher 1, due to it being only one round now. What's most curious is that Witcher 1+2 try to sell dice poker as a game of skill, when it's nearly entirly luck-based, wheras Gwent from Witcher 3 is sold much more as a game of chance, while most often skill (in deckbuilding) decides the winner.